# how to build executible bin with shared library using Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, linker, android-ndk, shared-libraries

how to build executable bin with a given shared library using Android-NDK R8 ??
i tried to make a bin by make a PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY of a given shared library,
but always occur that "error: undefined reference to 'av_free_packet(AVPacket*)'
".

my android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
DEFINES += \
           -DTARGET_POSIX \
           -DTARGET_LINUX \
           -D_LINUX \
           -DTARGET_ANDROID \
           -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS 

######################################
#build ffmpeg prebuilt lib
######################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libavcodec.a 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES +=$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavfilter  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libavfilter.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES +=$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavformat  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libavformat.a  
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES +=$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libavutil.a  
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES +=$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libpostproc  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libpostproc.a   
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES +=$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libswresample  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libswresample.a   
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES +=$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libswscale  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libswscale.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES +=$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


######################################
#build thread lib
######################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= player
base := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ......

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -Wall -fexceptions $(DEFINES)  
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -L../jni/lib/lib  -lavcodec -lavformat  -lavutil -lavfilter -lpostproc  -lswscale -lswresample

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libavcodec \
                          libavformat \
                          libavutil \
                          libavfilter \
                          libpostproc \
                          libswscale \
                          libswresample 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Is your intention to build ffmpeg with shared libs? You will have troubles launching this thing on user devices. I'd suggest going for static libs when you need an executable.

Comment: but i changed to use static libs, the error still occur

Comment: Can you post your Android.mk file?

Comment: ok,the Android.mk as follows. and the using shared library at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780986/error-undefined-reference-to-av-free-packetavpacket-when-use-ndk-to-compil